# after create changes the devise confirmation token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I have implemented devise for authentication I am facing a problem I need to change some of my user object's attribute right after its created and I am also using confirmable module when I update my user object in after_create call back it automatically changes the confirmation_token and I get error invalid confirmation token first time. If I resend confirmation email it works my questions how can I prevent devise to change confirmation_token or send confirmation email automatically so that I can send updated/correct token.